# Proxy to connect to Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: php, proxy, apple-push-notifications

I am using NetworkRedux shared hosting and following the APNs setup instructions at http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 then I get this:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to
connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in
FILEPATH on line 21
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out
```

It looks like they are blocking this, lame. **Is there a may I can use my same script including my private key and everything to connect to a proxy that will connect to Apple?** I am not interested in services that "do push for you" or web APIs or anything. I want a temporary fix that I can build off of and then remove when I migrate this to a real host, that doesn't block those ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is possible, but direct is the best way if possible in your environment. If you have to use an HTTP Proxy, then all you need to do is connect to the proxy, then create an HTTP Tunnel through the proxy to Apple's servers - don't initiate the TLS with Apple until after the proxy connection is create. Here is some good documentation on creating such a HTTP Tunnel with PHP: http://kakku.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/proxy-hacks-final-httptunnel-tcpip-connections-over-plain-old-get-and-post-requests/